# JavaScript create PHP compact function equivalent using eval

Tags: javascript, php, eval

I have seen a few questions of about replicating PHP's compact function with JavaScript and answers were it was not possible if the vars are not in global scope or it is not recommend to use eval.

I tried giving  eval a try and it seems to work

What are the issues with the below apart from the fact that the compact function can not be not be declared outside the scope of the vars you are trying to compact.

```
function somefunc() {
    // in compact func, eval will run eval('a') and not eval(a) so this is safe
    var a = 'alert("this will not run")', 
        b = 'bbb';

    var compact = function() {
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var key = arguments[i];
            var value = eval(key);
            obj[key] = value;
        }
        return obj;
    }
    console.log(compact('a', 'b')) //  {a: "alert("this will not run")", b: "bbb"}
}
somefunc();
```

Workaround for inner variables collisions and scope issue mentioned above

```
function somefunc() {
    // in compact func, eval will run eval('a') and not eval(a) so this is safe
    var a = 'alert("this will not run")', 
        b = 'bbb';

  var compact = eval("(function(){for(var ___$$$1={},___$$$2=0;___$$$2<arguments.length;___$$$2++){var ___$$$3=arguments[___$$$2],___$$$4=eval(___$$$3);___$$$1[___$$$3]=___$$$4}return ___$$$1})");

    console.log(compact('a', 'b')) //  {a: "alert("this will not run")", b: "bbb"}
}
somefunc();
```

Comment: `compact('i', 'key', 'value', 'obj', 'arguments')` won't work. ES6 provides a built-int solution for this: Short object notation: `console.log({a, b})`.

Comment: Good point about the inner vars, but we could still work around that by creating the compact function itself using eval and giving the inner vars cryptic names, nothing we can do about 'arguments' and 'this' though. Of course is this not pretty better to use a ES6 transplier for now.

Comment: One other issue is that this code will break when minified, come to think of it I am not sure how the ES6 shorthand will work with minificaion either.